# Page curl on iOS: Keep showing toolbar like in standard Maps app

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uiviewcontroller, page-curl

I am trying to achieve the same effect as in the Maps app: A page curl where the toolbar is not part of the curl. See this for example:

http://www.patentlyapple.com/.a/6a0120a5580826970c0120a8a7172c970b-800wi

Currently this is the code that starts the curl up:

```
MKTModalViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapOptions"];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The current view controller (the self above) contains a map and a toolbar. With the code above, the whole page gets curled up. I would like only the map to curl up while the toolbar stays at the same place.

Does anyone know how to do that? Is I want to do possible at all (relatively easily)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in the Maps app, the UIToolbar is actually the toolbar owned by UINavigationController. Make sure your UIToolbar is not a new one you added to your ViewController.

Try something like this in your UIViewController:

```
// add your buttons and controls to self.navigationController.toolbar;
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

MKTModalViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapOptions"];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Not sure if that will compile off the top of my head, but it should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you propose: Both with a UINavigationController and with a new toolbar. But no luck with either.